# How to Stop Style Tag

Tags: html, css

I have currently designed a webpage to have a header that follows the user as they scroll down when I did this I used style tags. But now everything I link or try to list gains these attributes and I cant figure out how to stop it.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>About</title>
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>About</title>
      </head>

      <body bgcolor="#E6E6FA">

    <style>
    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: fixed;

    }

    li {
        float: left;
    }

    a:link, a:visited {
        display: inline;
        width:550px;
        height: auto;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 25px;
        color:  #D2291F;
        background-color: #30166B;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 20px;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    a:hover, a:active {
    color: #30166B;
        background-color: #D2291F;
    }
    </style>

    </head>
    <body>

    <ul>
      <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
      <li><a href="Contact Us.html">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="About.html">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="Awards.html">Awards</a></li>
     </ul>

    <br>
    <br>

        <p>


        <br>
    My Co-op NBE was created in 1985, since then the company has been helping the Orillia area
    with all IT issues both personal and commercial. The team at NBE has won many <a href="Awards.html">Awards</a> and specializes in everything IT including:
  </body>
</html>
```

I shortened the html as much as possible to paste it so how would I make this style stuff only apply to the header and not the rewards link in the chat

This is all I want in the header and affected by the style

```
  <ul>
      <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
      <li><a href="Contact Us.html">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="About.html">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="Awards.html">Awards</a></li>
     </ul>
```

Comment: Give the header and ID and apply the CSS to that instead of all unordered lists.

Comment: Also, you may want to look at your start and end tags for head and body. Currently you have two body start tags, conflicting ones too: one with a bgcolor attribute and one without.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS currently specifies styles for ALL `<ul>` elements. If you want it to only apply to your nav, you have to be more specific by using a class, like "sticky". So first, add 'class="sticky"' to your `<ul>` element, like this:

```
<ul class="sticky">
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="Contact Us.html">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="About.html">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="Awards.html">Awards</a></li>
 </ul>
```

and the css, if you want all of the styles to ONLY apply to your "sticky" nav, should be:

```
<style>
ul.sticky {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;

}

ul.sticky li {
    float: left;
}

ul.sticky li a:link, ul.sticky li a:visited {
    display: inline;
    width:550px;
    height: auto;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 25px;
    color:  #D2291F;
    background-color: #30166B;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

ul.sticky li a:hover, ul.sticky li a:active {
color: #30166B;
    background-color: #D2291F;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Or any of many alternatives, such as using `body > ul:first-child` for a selector, using an actual `<nav>` element etc.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know you could class like that, so I learnt something new thanks!